# Is there a performance difference between saveAs() and exportDocument()?

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

When exporting an image in Photoshop, is there a performance difference between `app.activeDocument.exportDocument()` and `app.activeDocument.saveAs()`?

Comment: What keeps you from benchmarking it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on some tests it looks live saveAs() is about 1.5 to 2 times faster than exportDocument().